# SSL Certificate for WSGI application

Tags: django, ssl, django-wsgi

I have a Django project that I deployed using only the WSGI server provided by Django(no webserver like apache, ngnix ...).
The problem is that I want to upload an SSL certificate for the HTTPS version of the website. How can I do it please ?
Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) and [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) for the HTTPS version of your site.

I recommend you use web servers such as Nginx or Apache for practicing. Besides, your application runs better.

You can read this easy guide from [medium](https://medium.com/@panzelva/deploying-django-website-to-vps-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04-db9b387ad19d).

If you are using Ubuntu or other Linux distributions:

```
# adding certbot repository
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot

# do not forget to update your dependencies after adding some repo
sudo apt update

# installing certbot
sudo apt-get install python-certbot-nginx

# pointing certbot to your domain
sudo certbot --nginx -d yourdomain.com -d www.yourdomain.com
```